# Vuex Store - Get data from state store for viewing

Tags: vue.js, vuex

How do I get the data from an object in state store to display in my component fields?

**Vuex:**

```
state:
 books: [], // this object has id, title, genre

actions:
 allBooks(context) {
      axios
      .get('/api/books')
      .then(response => context.commit('SET_BOOKS', response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },

mutations:
 SET_BOOKS(state, books) {
      state.books = books
    },
```

**Component:**

```
 created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('allBooks')
    },

    computed: {
      storeBooks() {
        return this.$store.state.books
      },
    },
```

Now when I load the page of books, I want the fields for id, title and genre to be populated with data from the vuex store. I can't access the data in the object one by one. I tried using `this.books.id = this.$store.books.id` and it's not working.

Comment: `this.$store.books` should be `this.$store.state.books` and u can't access to `id` of a array doing; `this.$store.books.id`, there you should to iterate your list to access to each object of the array

Comment: My bad it was a typo and thank you for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by saying it's not working? Have you tried displaying `storeBooks` computed on the page in that component? What do you see when you do this:

```html
<div>{{ storeBooks }}</div>
```

If you want to display every book, just use a `v-for` loop:

```html
<div v-for="book in storeBooks" :key="book.id">
  {{ book.title }}
</div>
```

Comment: I could see the whole object but I can't get/display each data individually. If I wanted to display just a single data for example title only, will it be this.$store.state.books.title?

Comment: @JimERussel you already created computed `storeBooks` you can use that, you don't need to use `this.$store.state.books`. I updated the answer. If you just want to display 1 property of the element in a loop, just specify it `{{ book.title }}`

Comment: Follow-up question. Am I able to achieve this without the use of `v-for?`

Comment: @JimERussel yes, just like in javascript, specify the needed index in brackets, for example, to get the first element: `<div>{{storeBooks[0].title}}</div>`

Comment: @JimERussel glad I could help